# How to implement OIDC in old webforms projects using C#

Tags: c#, webforms, openid-connect, owin, okta

I have an old project which is C# and was written many years ago. We upgrade it to 2019 but the code is the same and is not changed and it is web form. It is not MVC.

The project is consist if multiple aspx pages. There is a class which implemented `IHttpModule`

For security, I would like to implement OIDC. For that I created an application in the provider (Okta), got client and secrets.

I also installed Owin package and created an Owin `Startup` class.

I added this code to the startup class:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebCookieManager(),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        { 
            OnResponseSignIn = context =>
            {
                context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
                context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60); //60
                context.Properties.IsPersistent = false;
            }
         }
    });

var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        ClientId = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret,
        Authority = _issuer,
        RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
        ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
        RedeemCode = true,
        SaveTokens = true,
        Scope = $"{OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile} {OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess}",
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = _issuer,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            NameClaimType = "name",
            ValidAudience = clientId,
         },
         UsePkce = false,
         Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
         {
             SecurityTokenValidated = OnSecurityTokenValidated,
             AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
         }
   };
   app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
}
```

I also implemented `OnAuthenticationFailed` to redirect to an error page and `OnSecurityTokenValidated` to get the `id_token` and `access_token`.

So far so good.

Normally in ASP.NET MVC applications we create a custom filter normally add an [[authorize] attribute to the controllers that needs authorization however I do not have any controllers.

What do u suggest in this case so I could authorize and send user to login page if not authorized.

Previously this application was used iv-header and was handled using Gateway but now we want to use OIDC.

In ASP.NET MVC, we would inherit from `IAuthenticationFilter` and could implement `OnAuthenticationChallenge` to do that for us.

I am wondering how can I enforce security on certain `.aspx` pages so it redirects the user to sign in widget?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it should be possible to "plug in" this new authentication provider.

There are some "guides", and I would even consider creating a new blank web site application, .net framework, and choose OWIN for the security provider.

I think to test/play with that production site is "too many" things at one time so to speak.

Then swap in your provider.

Then import the existing web pages into this new site.

This would/should result in a basic web site, and one that has a newer authentication provider "hooked" in.

That older site most likely is using FBA (forms based authentication). However, the standard web site templates for web forms, even those in vs2022? They will create a webforms site with OWIN authentication. I can't say how close using OWIN to ODIC is, but they are similar in operation.

To be fair, the above is not a whole lot of help, but only suggests that swapping out the authentication provider can be done, and is supported. (my apologies for not helping more in this area).

Another road would be to inherit the existing provider, as there are 3 provider classes, and while each has quite a few methods, you can limit to just using a few of them.

There are 2 providers you have to inherit:

```
SqlProvder
RoleProvider
```

Visual Studio can by inheriting, will scaffold all the methods for you.

There are quite a few methods, and MOST are to allow built in commands such as creating a new user, changing password for existing users etc.

So, one would do well to figure out what "admin" pages exist on that site, and how much work and time was spent on "user management" of logons?  And did they use perhaps the IIS admin screens for this? (from what I can tell, these "admin" pages are NOT included in recent webform templates, and have not been included for many years now - probably 10 years now).

Since we were using some desktop software to manage the users, then I really did not have to care about building a 100% "perfect" interface based on the IIS authentication system.

So, one road is to build your own custom authentication provider (based on existing FBA). Thus, if  you follow the api and standards? Then those web based IIS screens will continue to work, and work without having to change ANY of the existing code for things like new users, password changes etc. Or even if a user is active, or not.

And this would also mean existing password re-directs and logic need not be changed for the existing site. And that brings us to your next question:

> how can I enforce security on certain .aspx pages so it redirects the user to sign in widget?

If/when security is setup correctly, then that process is all automatic.

While you "can" secure a single web page by say a user having membership in a given role? That of course is a very rare setup, and one tends to secure "groups" of pages by a given role.

And that means in most cases, you secure by grouping such web pages in a folder.

Say like this:

[image]

So, to secure each of the above "sections" of the site?

Then you drop in a web.config file for each folder.

In above, say the site admin folder? Well, we only allow users with a role of "SiteAdmin" into that folder.

So, you use web.config to do this. (that's how this is done in web land).

Once you secured that folder? Then if a user attempts to use any page in that folder? if they don't have membership in that role (in this example "siteAdmin"), then they are automatic directed to the logon page.

The above Site admin web config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
            <allow roles="SiteAdmin" />
        <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

So, at that point, you are done. No code behind, or no attributes to the web pages are required here. In fact, even if you call/use ajax from the client side, if the user not logged in, then even your web method api's are secured. (the user will require membership in that givne role).

So the use of "web.config" and placing a web.config in each folder is typical how this security was setup for webforms. There is no code, or even changes to the web pages as a result, and they are secured.

Now, of course often in code behind, membership in a given security role will OFTEN occur. This would be to hide/show menus, or even re-direct the user in question to a different page.

So, in my main menu bar (a master page), you see code like this:

```
 Me.m8.Visible = True
 Me.mAdmin.Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole("SiteAdmin")
 Me.mStaff.Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole("Staff")
```

So, above is code behind, and it hides/shows some menu options based on the users membership in a given role.

While the above code behind does hide/show a menu option to allow the user to navigate to say some of those "site admin" pages?

Well, due to the web.config file (which controls security) in that folder, then the pages are still secured and prevented from being used by IIS. This includes web api calls and end points (if that site was using such code - it probably was not).

I note the above, since depending on how large and how much code exists for this site? You want to ensure that boatloads of code behind, and years of setting up security for sections of the site are not broken by you swapping out the authentication provider. The issue not changing the security provider, the issue is how much code and moving parts in the existing site will you break when doing this!!!

So, with above "web.config" file placed in each folder?
You should be able to see/find what security roles are setup in that site. Any attempt to use such a page will automatic trigger security, and a re-direct to the logon page. In fact, the URL will not only show a re-direct, but in most cases the target URL is included, and after a logon, the user can continue to that url/web page in question.

It looks like this:

[image]

The above is a un-secured page.

I'll paste in a URL of site admin, like this:

[image]

so, now, automatic, without code, then the logon page will intercept this, and we get this:

[image]

Note VERY close in above the URL. Note how IIS security settings directed me to the logon page, but note the extra parameter in the URL to re-direct after I logon (in other words, continue to the target URL, which required a logon, and one that has a role SiteAdmin).

And now after login in, then I get/see this:

[image]

So, in general, the intercept of a logon, and the security?

You don't write code, or even set any attributes or settings "per page".

You can I suppose secure ONE page by using the above web.confg file (the one in the root), but as a general rule, pages are grouped by a folder, and each folder will have that web.config for securing ALL of the pages in that folder by some defined role which the logged on user has membership in that role.

So, above is a quick/short summary of no doubt how the existing security works and is setup on that site.

The challenge here?
Not to break all those years of code and security settings that the existing site has and uses.

So, I would actually create a blank new fresh site, and use OWIN, and then try to setup and get OIDC working on that test webform site.

As long as code behind works testing for "role membership", and as long as the existing web config files work, then you can implement that OIDC into the production site.

However, if you don't get the IIS security model working, then you of course will break a lot of code, and a lot of security settings that no doubt have been setup and created for that site over many years.

There is a example here of using oidc with webforms:

https://www.codemag.com/article/0907061/Implementing-OpenID-Authentication-in-an-ASP.NET-Application

So, I would do this testing for the first round against a brand new blank webforms site. (if you don't see the templates in vs2022 to create such sites, you have to go to tools->get features and select the older templates to be installed for visual studio).

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. Since i do not want to change a lot of things, I I tried to use my existing cs class which is inheritted from HttpModule? This class runs before accessing any aspx page because it inherits from IhtpModule for Init there is a call to PreExecuteHandler already. I Created Owin startup class and in the beginning of this handler i added follwoing code

Comment: if(!request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
  new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
  OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

return;
} . It comes in this 2 times first time nothing happens and second time it throws error

Comment: I expect the provider's login page and in this case Okta login page appears but nothing happens at first time and on second time it throws error "No owin Environment item was found in the context." I do not thing the issue is Owin startup as iI have added both <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/> and also <add key="owin:appStartup" value="Assembly.Startup" />. Also I test owin with adding app.Run with hellowold which worked see below 
app.Run(context =>
{  context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
   return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");})so should not be owin

Comment: I am wonder if it is ok to use the combination of IHTTPModule and Owin which I am trying or that is causing the issue? I like to use this combination as IHttpModule will run on each page and it has some existing logic that i want to keep but i need to be ale to execute the challange and see th login page. Any idea would be apprecaited

Comment: Hum, I think one major question is do you want to keep existing security settings, and have IIS do the work of intercepting a logon (and re-directs) as my above shows, or not? This certainly can be done with OWIN, and I not actually attempted to do this with OIDC (to be honest, not really sure how close they are). This is much I suggest creating a brand new webforms site, but click the options to include OWIN.  The result is a working webforms site that IIS respects and continues to use existing secuirty model (and the existing web.config security settings). I would then change owin to oidc.

Comment: if OIDC now works, the you can lift that setup into your existing site, and that would be the path of least efforts. I guess the question is as noted, do you want to respect and use the current security model that works with IIS, and thus does most of the dirty work, and does not require much code beyond having that new security system work with IIS settings. I have a current site that runs FBA, and I want to upgrade to OWIN, and the idea of creating a new webform site that works with OWIN means I can grab/steal/lift the code and setting for OWIN to that older existing site, and it should work

Comment: however, while the above seems to be a good approach, I not yet done this, so I can't say how easy this is. As noted, the other approach is to plug in the sqlprovider security model into OIDC. This would as noted require code of about 8 routines in sqlprovider, and probably about 4 more in the role provider. Either way, I would test/play with a OWIN site, and then move it over to OIDC, and see how that goes (that's a whole lot less work then messing with a production site). Once you get OIDC working with test site, then you have a good basis how to upgrade the production site.

Comment: this is one of those examples that until I done the conversion, I can't say the best road here.  (my apologies). However, the above is at least the road and path I would take for such a change over.  And to be fair, I still very familiar with webforms security, so a change over probably means I would want to continue to have the IIS + webforms security model work, which is most automatic. Having stated above, I can only apologize for not being able to help more, and hopefully I do that conversion over to OWIN soon, and thus have more to say and more experience doing this.